# i can't get resolution options and i get message: "Unknown Display"

Tags: display

when i changed the `VGA` cable, i found that the resolution has been changed, and i can't get resolution options from the display settings because i get message **Unknown Display**, i think that because the VGA cable, so that the device the computer can't recognize the cable or something like that, i don't know, i hope you can help me in that,

[![Screenshot of display settings][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghlvo.png